# Where is the code in npgsql for converting to and from C# and postgres binary protocol

Tags: npgsql

Hello I am new to npgsql and postgres binary wire protocol. But I would like to understand it better.
Can someone point me to the code sections that are taking binary protocol for RowDescription and DataRow and converting into c# types and also doing the reverse going from c# types into binary protocol for RowDescription and DataRows?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the PostgreSQL wire protocol - including the RowDescription and DataRow messages - is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-formats.html).

In the Npgsql source code, RowDescription is handled [here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/main/src/Npgsql/BackendMessages/RowDescriptionMessage.cs) (see the other files for other messages). DataRow is a bit special - it's generally handled in [NpgsqlDataReader](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/main/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlDataReader.cs), but the handling is more complex (since it can be huge and may be streamed).